# University asked everyone to upload offer letter to a shared drive folder. Is this legal?

Tags: job-offer, india, legal

My university has asked every student with an offer to post his/her offer letter in a google drive link.

Almost every company who hire here are US based. Specific US city wise: San Jose, Seattle, San Francisco. Mainly US west cost : Californian companies dominating followed by 3-4 Wall street banks like Goldman Sachs, Morgan Stanley etc.

Coming to the college itself, it's like an Indian government institution, they will not listen to "rules". They will threaten students on withholding their bachelor's degrees if they don't agree to uploading their offer.

Almost every offer letter in the shared folder has NDA (Non Disclosure Agreement). Now I have read a few resources on whether an offer letter is confidential or not and I am still on the fence about it's confidentiality. But there are some offers which clearly mention that the letter itself is confidential too.

My questions are:
- Is this legal under the terms of offer letter?

- What are the consequences of uploading the letter here?
- What happens if the companies find out about this?

Edit:

- University is in India. In Indian colleges, ok the last year of bachelors degree a "placements season" is conducted where companies come and recruit students. This "placements" is done by a "placements department" and that's the department which has asked students to upload their letters.

Comment: I'm curious to know what the purpose of this is from the university's point-of-view.  Attracting new students, reputation versus other similar universities, meeting government set metrics on employment-after-degree, or ???

Comment: What prevents you from telling that no one offered you any job?

Comment: Just to clarify, where is your university? In India? In the U.S.? Somewhere else?

Comment: Having studied in India, I know that the threat of "withholding the degree" is an empty threat that will never be executed. From what you've written, I see that they have not yet threatened you. It's an assumption you are making. I would typically ask more details from the person who made the request and then speak with the (sensible) higher authorities in the college if necessary, to help them prevent the college reputation from getting dragged through the mud.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Is this legal under the terms of offer letter?

Typically not. Most US companies will require you to sign an NDA as part of the interview process and the offer letter is typically covered by this NDA. This is not a crime, but it's clearly a violation of contract. Read the paperwork that you have signed carefully and if you can't figure it out, have it reviewed by a lawyer.

> What are the consequences of uploading the letter here?

Depending on what exact paperwork you have signed, it's a violation of a contract or NDA.

> What happens if the companies find out about this?

Depends on circumstances and the company, but most US companies will NOT take this lightly. A violation of an NDA is a severe infraction and always a good reason for "termination with cause". Offer letters are considered confidential, and most companies are very protective of salary and offer data. Most likely outcome is, that they will rescind the offer, put you on a do not hire list and may share the infraction of other tech companies which would make it hard for you to get a job in the future. It is less likely that would go after you for damages, although they technically could.

The question you didn't ask

> "What should I do?"

This is a bizarre request. The college is asking you do something that is likely in violation of a contract that you have signed and that may have serious negative consequences for their students. It may very well get the college blacklisted by US employers.

Step #1 would be to try to talk to someone and make them understand that this is potentially very harmful to the students and the college as well. If they stick to their request and threaten to withhold your degree, you need to get a lawyer involved. This is serious.

DO NOT post your offer letter, unless you have explicit permission in writing from your employer to do so (which you are unlikely to get). You can also ask your recruiter for help and advice. Maybe a letter from your employer stating that posting of the offer letter violates your agreement and would result in you losing the offer, would help communicating with the college

Comment: Thank you for answering. As commented before, I will be taking up this matter with my company's HR. I'll also advice my friends to do the same with their companies.

Comment: Get it in writing from your prospective employer, signed by someone in HR or Legal  willing to do this and upload that, if your college hassles you point them to the signee.

Comment: There's some nuance here around "most companies are very protective of salary and offer data." The letter itself may be a confidential company document covered by NDA. However, workers in the US (and it's not entirely clear to me, or perhaps anyone, that this inherently includes workers who haven't yet started their employment) have [broad rights to discuss their salary and working conditions](https://twc.texas.gov/news/efte/salary_discussions.html) under the National Labor Relations Act. It may (talk to an employment lawyer) suit everyone's needs to share the key information, not the letter.

Comment: @ZachLipton For what it's worth here's the [definition of employee](https://www.law.cornell.edu/definitions/uscode.php?def_id=29-USC-1193469614-1967365142&term_occur=23&term_src=title:29:chapter:7:subchapter:II:section:158) used for the [relevant law](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/29/157). IANAL and I'm not sure what case law is on this. My personal reading of this would be that prospective employees - who are not yet employees - would not be covered by this law, but I could definitely be wrong.

Comment: I am not a lawyer either, but as far as I know the right to discuss salary (and working conditions) only extends to discussions with other employees, union reps, etc. You do not have a blanket right to disclose your salary publicly or to

Comment: ... non-employee entities.

Answer (score 19):

Whenever you ask a question about whether or not an action is legal, ***ask an attorney.***  No opinion here (unless it happens to come from an attorney) has any legal weight.  As my retired-attorney father used to say, people can sue for anything, at any time, for any reason.  Violating NDA (which in this case means you're revealing competitive information about hiring procedures) is a big deal and can seriously cost you — not the university.

One solution is [provided by 520](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/125394/869): ask your employer for a version of the letter to give to the university, or for their permission to upload the letter you received.

Another solution is to inform the university that you are under NDA and cannot upload the letter without violating it.

If the university is so childish that it would withhold your degree simply because you're unwilling to violate a legal agreement with your new employer, then perhaps you should consider suing.  Granted, I don't know a thing about Indian law — but my knee-jerk reaction is the argument of loss-of-income-due-to-hiring-interference would cost them a boatload of cash.  Here in the U.S., you'd have lawyers lining up to take the case.

Comment: Okay, understood. Thank you for the answer. About asking the company, should I just directly state the matter and or any particular formal way of going around it? For now, my company's HR is the source of contact, I haven't yet started work, my onboarding is due in January.

Comment: As common as this sounds in India, I wouldn't be surprised if the company hasn't run into the problem before.  I would not expect formality to be an issue.  Call the HR department, explain that your university is asking for the offer letter to be uploaded, and ask if they have a procedure for that process.  If they don't, ask them if they could provide a simple confirmation-of-employment letter (very much akin to what @520 has suggested).  They'll be nice about all this.  Yours isn't the first university to do silly things.

Comment: Okay, will contact HR and take necessary steps. Thank you.

Comment: Even if advice here comes from a lawyer, it doesn't come from your lawyer.  law.stackexchange.com is good for general principles, but if you need legal advice you need to find a lawyer.  In the US, your local Bar Association is likely to set up low-price consultations.

Comment: If the university is so childish as to withhold degrees for this, *and the US hiring companies learn that fact*, the OP's question quickly become irrelevant, since there will be no offer letters to post. It takes years to build a good reputation, but only seconds to lose it for ever.

Answer (score 4):

Vincent.  This may not be a direct answer to your questions, but I think it may be helpful.  You could send an anonymous email to whatever is the closest to their internal ethics department, or perhaps to their legal department.  Attach the instructions which were sent to everyone.  Explain your concerns.  Tell them that if the instructions are in accord with their university policies, then they need take no action at this time, but that you thought they should be aware of the requirement.

I think you would find that they would quickly cease the requirement.

Comment: ethics departments are powerless in IITs (which it's clear that this institution is)

Answer (score 3):

By and large, job offers are confidential so disclosing the offer letter and salary is forbidden.  When two large organizations ask you to do contradicting things, first obey *the law*,  then obey any *legal contract* (which is what applies here: your NDA with the company is the controlling factor), then follow your *self-interest*: your employer pays you, and university is in the past.

---

Most likely, the university wants proof of an offer letter to provide **evidence of a marketing claim** the university wants to make: that they place X percent of their students in good jobs.  Some colleges have gotten in [big trouble for that](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/beware-colleges-job-placement-claims/) in the past, and at least in the USA many colleges are "student loan mills", and courts have [canceled student loans](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/grade-point/wp/2016/07/20/did-your-college-mislead-you-about-job-prospects-it-might-become-far-easier-to-have-your-loans-forgiven/) from colleges who lied about placement.

So it is likely management, on advice of the Legal Dept., has told staff in no uncertain terms to capture that data from every single student *no exceptions*, and with the fervor and absolutism that comes with edicts from Legal.  Staff uses Google Drive to ease their workload and prove that the student originated it (it's not faked).

Tempting though it may be to fake one, I do not advise that.  Then, the university would have plausible grounds to accuse you of misconduct.

---

I would attempt to find out what data the university *really* needs and why they need it.

For instance, *once you are employed*, the mere fact that you *are* employed is publishable.  The employer would cheerfully give a letter to that effect.

Salary, again, is not going to happen, as that would needlessly put them at disadvantage when negotiating salary with other candidates.  It's a different deal if Government hires you, as salaries are [typically public information](http://gogovernment.org/government_101/pay_and_the_general_schedule.php).

Comment: The vast majority of non-government U.S. employers are legally prohibited from taking any action against you for sharing wage or salary information. Granted, this protection may only extend to current employees. I'm not sure whether prospective employees would be covered under the definition of 'employee' used in the law ([29 USC 157](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/29/157)).

Comment: @reirab did you send the right link? That's for forming a labor union.

Comment: Yes, it's the right link. Presumably, it's the "engage in other concerted activities for the purpose of collective bargaining **or other mutual aid or protection**" that covers sharing salary information. See [this explanation](https://twc.texas.gov/news/efte/salary_discussions.html) that Zach Lipton linked in another comment for more detail. So, in this case, that particular part of the NDA is unenforceable, as it contradicts U.S. federal law. It's a common company policy, but also one that can't be enforced.

Comment: You can also read about it on [NPR](https://www.npr.org/2014/04/13/301989789/pay-secrecy-policies-at-work-often-illegal-and-misunderstood), [GovDocs](https://www.govdocs.com/can-employees-discuss-pay-salaries/) (a labor law compliance firm), the [Society for Human Resource Management](https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/tools-and-samples/hr-qa/pages/prohibitdiscussingsalaries.aspx), and the [NLRB](https://www.nlrb.gov/rights-we-protect/rights/employee-rights) (the federal agency tasked with enforcing this law.)

Comment: @reirab: that's  not how it works. Yes, there are laws but the intent of a law and what happens in the real world are two entirely different things. Starting your new job with a legal conflict, is the end of your career there and most likely in the entire industry as well. The law may help you to squeeze out a bit of severance or get you dummy seat at a desk for a while, but why would you do this?

Comment: And again, every one of those refs is about collective bargaining, note the phrase "AMONG employees" used in all these refs.  That is a specific use that is protected.  Other uses are not protected, and the university's collecting this data from *one* employee of that firm for unstated uses, clearly isn't protected, *because it's unstated*, but also because it's obviously *not* union organizing.

Comment: Anyway the law is useless because you can't sue in secret.  Even if *somehow* you prevail... every company now knows students from university X are taught to violate NDA. "Graduating from university X" is not a protected class... **so they Stop Getting Interviews**. University staff calls up big employers, learns the reason, cancels the policy and begs US industry to forgive. That's where this foolishness ends.  The university obeying the law.

Comment: @Harper Note that they state explicitly that the intent to collectively bargain is _not_ required to be protected under this law. " the National Labor Relations Board (NLRB) has taken the position for decades now that employers may not prohibit employees from discussing their pay and benefits, and that any attempts to do so actually violate the NLRA. Courts have basically uniformly supported that position. Moreover, those particular sections of the NLRA apply to both union and non-union employees, so **there is no exception made for companies where the employees are non-unionized.**"

Comment: That said, you're correct that it is addressing employees sharing information with each other, not with a third party. I'm not sure how courts have ruled in regards to sharing with a third party.

Comment: @Hilmar I completely agree with you that it would be _imprudent_ to share the information in this case, even if doing so is protected by law. I was just pointing out that sharing that information is not normally breach of contract as the answer suggests, as such contracts aren't enforceable in most cases in the U.S.

Comment: @reirab of course non-union shops have the right to organize, otherwise the would be no new unions.   ......yeah, there's no evidence that *even 2 people* from his class work for company X, so there is no "each other" in need of protection. Only a third party with an obvious motive unrelated to labor law.

Comment: @Harper If you read the GovDocs link above, it cites several NLRB decisions, which have indeed decided that sharing wage information with third parties is indeed a protected action. Whether that's the original intent of the law or not is another matter, but it's being interpreted and enforced very broadly, pretty much completely banning any attempts at prohibiting covered employees from sharing salary or wage information. For example, Service Merchandise was found in violation of NLRA for even having such a policy and was required to remove it entirely and inform its employees of the removal.

Comment: The notice that Service Merchandise was required to post to their employees included, "WE WILL NOT distribute, maintain, or enforce rules prohibiting you from discussing your wages or other terms or conditions of employment with others."

Answer (score 2):

You could ask your prospective employer for a letter that you can share with the university, or if you're really out of options, you can make one up. Given that these letters are under NDA anyway, it's highly unlikely they will be publicising them. All a fake letter would have to contain is your name, the name of the employer and the name of the person who sent you the message, and some general fluff about being accepted. None of that will be NDA material. Don't put in any information about start times, or office locations. If they won't listen to laws, feel free to bypass theirs when their rules contravene laws.

Comment: Would blurring out certain parts of the letter be fine legal wise? Or should I just create a new document with relevant details?

Comment: From a legal perspective, blurring out the relevant parts could work but you'd need to know what all the relevant parts are. It sounds like your institution MAY have a hissy fit if they don't think they have the unredacted document though (ask them about this). If they want unredacted, make a new document and make it look like the original style-wise.

Comment: Got it. It's better to make a separate document. Since the deadline is a week away, I'd rather wait a bit more.

Comment: If you were going to do that, I would start with Pentagon letterhead, and then redact *every single word*.  I would've said CIA letterhead, but realistically the CIA wouldn't even do *that*.